# Orientation Problem in Android OS 2.3,need help

Tags: android

I am developing an android application by Android OS 2.3,My app run in Nexus OS 2.3,In Orientation,my apps has closed.In logcate,display following error display in screen

```
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mumbaiway/com.mumbaiway.newdetail.Info}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #280: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #280: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at com.mumbaiway.newdetail.Info.onCreate(Info.java:127)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     ... 11 more
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     ... 25 more
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:450)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:326)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:85)
04-09 15:38:46.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(850):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:81)
```

How to solve this problem in Android OS 2.3

Thanks Friends,
JRIck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not destroying your bitmap which caused out of memory situation. Call bitmap.recycle() as soon as you are done with it

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your error, this is the line you should be worried about:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

You are using up too much memory. There could be all sorts of things going on, a start might be as @Vinoth said to look at your bitmaps, and how you are destroying (or not!) them. Maybe you have a memory leak, and while turning you start a new activity, leak the old one, and have double the amount of stuff? That's all just guessing ofcourse, but the trouble is in the memory usage :)

Comment: @Thanks for your Reply,I need solutions for "i want to recycle all used resource in activity's on destroy() method,How is possible?